# Correct handling of application URIs from Unity Dash

Tags: unity, application-development, python, gtk3

At some point, Unity changed the Uri type it returned when a drag-n-drop operation occurred of applications from the Unity Dash to a Gtk window in an app I wrote.  In 13.04 (Unity 7.0), the data call back received a text/uri-list with the full path, e.g. file://usr/share/applications/APP.desktop

Now however, it's a test/uri-list like this:  application://APP.desktop

How do I get it to give me the full path to APP.desktop? Or can I use the uri to get an AppInfo object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/python/Unity-7.0.html), you should be able to use the get_path of the AppInfoManager object

Running the following in the python interpreter:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Unity
>>> a = Unity.AppInfoManager.get_instance()
>>> a.get_path("gedit.desktop")
'/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop'
```

As you can see, just passing the desktop file-name returns the full-path to the desktop filename.

Thus, from your drag-drop app - ensure you add the uri target:

```
widget.drag_dest_add_uri_targets()
```

connect to the drag_data_get method

```
connect("drag-data-get", self.on_drag_data_get)

def on_drag_data_received(self, widget, drag_context, x,y, data,info, time):
    print (data.get_uris())
```

Split out from `application://app.desktop` (`string.split(str, 1)[1]`) and feed that into the `appinfomanager.get_path()` method